# I have a corrupted windows 10 / Kubuntu install that is booting to grub rescue

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, windows

I have a corrupted bootloader and all I can get to is Grub Rescue - I was trying to get windows off my machine. I have Windows Media USB as well as a bootable Kubuntu ISO on USB. I need to try and get the machine to boot from the USB using Grub Rescue - I have tried following the SET commands but I am still getting errors. I have tried reinstalling GRUB as well but no go. What can I do?

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: What a computer boots to at start is controlled by the computer BIOS. It is not a software issue. You can not boot a USB from the Grub menu. You start an installed OS from that menu.